# Link mobile stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I have had problems with the responsive design, so I made a stylesheet for mobile named mobile.css and linked it in the header, but no change.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mobile' href='mobile.css' type='text/css' media='handheld' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Then in **mobile.css**

I havent copypasted all the code, because its a lot, but I know the code is right because it worked on my android phone, but not chrome and safari mobile.

```
@media handheld and (min-device-width : 768px)   
and (max-device-width : 1024px) (orientation: landscape) { 
@-ms-viewport{

    width: device-width;
}


code code code }

@media handheld and  (max-device-width : 480px) (orientation: landscape)  {      

@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
}
 code code code code }


  @media handheld and (max-width: 380px) (orientation: landscape) { 


@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
}

code code code }



 @media handheld and (orientation: landscape) { 

@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
}

code code }
```

Answer (score 1):

try use following media query specifically for chrome and safari

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   /* CSS rules */
}
```

Comment: No change, I have a also a -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5, should I do something with it?

Comment: what is your site link

Comment: why doesnt it load? Do I need to add more then "@media"?

Comment: The link was wrong, so I changed it to: http://retorikgruppen.se/wp-content/themes/pinboard/mobile.css no its not bland, but its worse now, now the menu dosnt show and still wrong...